# How to validate binary fraction with regex?

Tags: java, regex

Currently, I'm using regex `[^0-1]` to limit the binaryValue input with only 1's and 0's using find() in Matcher class.

```
String binaryValue = "10", strRegex = "[^0-1]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(strRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(binaryValue);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println("invalid");
}else{
    System.out.println("valid");
}
```

What I want to happen in my code is:
if the binaryValue only contains combinations of 0s and 1s and an optional one dot (decimal point), print "valid"

Valid format examples: 1001, 10.01, .1001, 1001.0

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Is your code not working?  If so, what error(s) or unexpected output are you getting?  What input causes the problem?

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "validate"?

Comment: How can I validate a binary fraction value with regex so that it only limits to only one dot?

Comment: @MarkGabrielleRecocoCay any comments you add to the comments section, you should also add to your question. Take a step back and imagine that we have no knowledge about your situation (because that's the reality) and ask the question in such a way to present us with as much information as necessary to answer it. As it stands, we don't have enough information to answer your question and your question might be closed for that reason.

Comment: Based on the current state of your question, I can only assume that you're looking for something like `^[01]+(\.[01]+)?$` (positive matches), but again, I'm not entirely sure. Sample strings of what to match or exclude from matches would be helpful here as well.

Comment: @MarkGabrielleRecocoCay that's better, but you should also identify proper and improper formats. For example, are `0.0`, `.0`, `0.`, `0.00`, or other similar variations positive or negative matches? What does *decimal* mean to you? Is your decimal point a dot `.` or a comma `,`?

Comment: Whenever I assign "^[01]+(\.[01]+)?$" in my regex, it says that my regex has invalid escape sequence.

Comment: @MarkGabrielleRecocoCay A backslash in a string literal in Java need to be escaped by another backslash. (So `"^[01]+(\\.[01]+)?$"`.)

Comment: I didn't know it's just the only problem I have with that regex. I've found similar questions of this but the another backslash in "^[01]+(\\.[01]+)?$" solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match the following binary decimal formats `1001`, `10.01`, `.1001`, `1001.0`, you can use the following:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eiHMHw/2)

```
^(?:[01]+|[01]*\.[01]+)$
```

How this works:

- `^` Asserts position at the start of the line
- `(?:[01]+|[01]*\.[01]+)` Match either of the following options

  - Option 1: `[01]+` Match any binary digit (0 or 1) one or more times
  - Option 2: `[01]*\.[01]+` Match any binary digit (0 or 1) zero or more times, followed by a literal dot character `.`, then by one or more binary digits (0 or 1) one or more times.
- `$` Asserts position at the end of the line

Please note that you'll need to escape backslashes in Java `^(?:[01]+|[01]*\\.[01]+)$`.

Also note that this will not match `0.` (or similar `1.`, `11.`, etc.) as this case is not explicitly included in the question. To match this case, you can use `(?:[01]+\.?|[01]*\.[01]+)`. These two regex patterns don't allow the string `.` to be matched.

<sub>Side note: All too often, users post questions without sufficient information and then never update their questions. Thank you for reading our comments and implementing the changes to your question! You're helping to improve this community.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### ^[01]+(.[01]+)?$

---

As [ctwheels had proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525570/how-to-validate-binary-fraction-with-regex#comment103376193_58525570). I explain what this regex does:

- **^** Asserts beginning of the line.
- **[01]+** At least one 0 or 1 must appear.
- **(.[01]+)** Then, a single dot, followed by at least one  0 or 1
  *could* appear. This is also considered the first capture group, as
  stated by those parentheses.
- **?** The previous element must appear zero or one time. This prevents matches with more than 1 dot.
- **$** Asserts end of the line.

---

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/bUbQyx/1)